Excel Conditional Formatting if these cells all say "YES" then make this cell green otherwise make it red
I have a full year of planning that has to happen, as well as time frames in which to get them done. What I'm trying to accomplish, is:
If these 6 (ie I69:N69) cells all say yes, then change the P69 cell colour to green, otherwise, leave it as red.
Now, I've got a formula that says =AND(I69="YES",J69="YES",K69="YES",L69="YES",M69="YES",N69="YES")
but this is based on 1 cell in the column. Is there a way to do it for the whole column which would look at it's adjacent row for the "YES" answers?
For context, the date in the P column are created by a formula from another column: =$D69-(7*12)
TIA


You can create a set of rules such as
=COUNTIF(A1:F1,"Yes")<6 - adjust cell addresses to suit you, pick red colour

=COUNTIF(A1:F1,"Yes")=6 - adjust cell addresses to suit you, pick green colour

After you conditionally format the first cell in your spreadsheet, P69, just drag it down and conditional formatting will apply to new cells as well.


Another suggestion for the green rule is:
=AND(I69:N69="Yes")

I am including another test for the red rule so that it doesn't format rows which are blank e.g.
=AND(P69<>"",OR(I69:N69<>"Yes"))

or slightly shorter
=(P69<>"")*OR(I69:N69<>"Yes")



You should just need to select the cells that you want to have filled (with the topmost cell of these highlighted/infocus) then you can just go to conditional formatting > new rule > 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format' and then you can use the formula: =AND($I69="YES",$J69="YES",$K69="YES",$L69="YES",$M69="YES",$N69="YES")
*HERE I HAVE ASSUMED 69 IS YOUR TOPMOST CELL IF IT IS NOT PLEASE CHANGE THE NUMBER TO THAT OF THE TOPMOST CELL (which should be in focus)
Then you can just - Click Format > Activate the Fill tab > Select green as fill colour. Excel is smart enough to infer that the formula changes the row value as it goes down the selected column

Using order of rules and "Stop if True"
In the example, with P69:P82 selected with P69 as the active cell,

"green" if =AND(I69:N69="YES"), check "Stop if True"
"red" for "Format only cells that contain" > "No blanks"
order the "red" below the "green"


